# Deleting certain number of whitespace after a certain number

Tags: c++

I am having some difficulty constructing a game board. I will post an image of what the grid should look like with a 4x4 layout, the picture helps you visualize what I am needing with my code.

The grid should have the last two whitespaces after the last column header removed

[image]

I've tried using a `break` statement if it reaches the last column number, but that has not helped.

The function in question is the `str()` function, it is my function that prints out the grid. I know where the specific line(s) where my code is not doing its job. I will mark it with a comment, to better understand.

scrambler.h

```cpp
#ifndef SCRAMBLER_H
#define SCRAMBLER_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Scrambler {
public:
  Scrambler(const string & path , const int size);
  string str();
  void try_move (const string& cmd);
  bool is_over();
  string display_solution();
  vector<string> get_words();
  vector<string>boardWords;
  int size;
};

#endif
```

scrambler.cpp

```cpp
#include "scrambler.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

Scrambler::Scrambler(const string &path, const int size) {
  ifstream file(path);
  vector<string> words;
  string wordLine;

  this->size = size;
  
  // string defaultVal = NULL;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    string line = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      line+=" ";
      
    }

    boardWords.push_back(line);

  }
  
  while (file >> wordLine) {
    words.push_back(wordLine);
  }

  int fileWordCount = words.size();
  //cout<<fileWordCount;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int rowSize = size;
    while (rowSize > 2) {
      int random = rand() % fileWordCount;
      string randWord = words.at(random);
      //boardWords.push_back(randWord);
      //cout<<randWord;
      if (rowSize >= randWord.size() && rowSize != 3) {
        boardWords.push_back(randWord);
      } 
      rowSize -= randWord.size();
    }
  }

}

string Scrambler::str() {
  int counter = 1;
  string dashes = "   ";
  string numbers = " ";
  string line = "";
  string board = "";

// this for loop and its contents are the problem in question, idk how to make it so there are not whitespaces at the end of the grid
  for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {    
    numbers += "   " + to_string(i);
    dashes += "----";
  }

  board += numbers + "\n" + dashes + "\n";
  for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
    int rowCounter = 1;
    line = "";
    line += to_string(rowCounter + k) + " | ";   
    int wordSize = boardWords[k].size();
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      if (j < wordSize) {
        char c = boardWords[k][j];
        string s(1, c);
        line += s + " | ";
      } else {
        line += "  | ";
      }
    }   
    board += line + "\n" + dashes;
    if (counter != size) {
      board += "\n";
    }
    counter++;   
  }
  // cout << board;
  return board;
}

void Scrambler::try_move(const string &cmd) {
  
}

bool Scrambler::is_over() {

  return true;
}

string Scrambler::display_solution() {

  return "hi";
}

vector<string> Scrambler::get_words() {
  vector<string> word;
  return word;
}
```

Here is my current output with a 4x4 grid.

```
    1   2   3   4
   ----------------
1 |   |   |   |   | 
   ----------------
2 |   |   |   |   | 
   ----------------
3 |   |   |   |   | 
   ----------------
4 |   |   |   |   | 
   ----------------
```

Comment: PSA: Try to avoid `using namespace std;` The `std::` prefix serves an important purpose.

Comment: What kind of output are you getting now? Where do you think the problem is?

Comment: tadman- the problem is in the first for loop of the str() func, specifically the ""numbers += "   " + to_string(i);"", which adds some white space to numbers, and then the column number/counter. I will attach my current output with a 4x4 grid at the end of it.

Comment: It's always worth deleting anything in the code not strictly relevant to the problem at hand. When working on things like this, it's also helpful to try and work with *test cases* that you can run automatically using a test suite.

Comment: EDIT: I JUST RESOLVED THIS

Comment: @MykitaZolov then either [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) explaining how you fixed it, or else delete the question.